# Improving join between shape and view in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins, performance, arccatalog

I have a problem with a simple join and I don't know what to do:

- I have a shapefile with 400,000 parcels, in this file I have only one column with the parcel id with an index.
- I have a Materialized View in Oracle with only 2,000 rows, this view has 4 columns, one of them is the parcel id also with an index.
- In ArcCatalog I added a new database connection to get the Materialized View.
- In ArcMap I added the shapefile and the materialized view with no problems. Displaying the data of each layer takes less than a second.
- In ArcMap I create a join by parcel id keeping only matching records.

At this step, when I open the attribute table it takes up to a minute to get the data and drawing the layer also takes a long time. Because of this, I can't use this mxd project at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, join takes time. I don't have any suggestion to improve the performance.

Hope, you may have tried with file geodatabase, it has better indexing capability and data storage limits and technically it is good to store your 400k polygon data.